# RxJava timeout conditionally

Tags: java, observable, rx-java

RxJava observable need to apply the timeout based on some condition. If the condition is false, it should not apply any timeout.

```
Observable<String> obs2 = Observable
        .fromCallable(longTask)
        .timeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) //Want to do this based on a condition
        .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable>() {
            @Override
            public Observable call(Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.println("Fallback task triggered");
                return null;
            }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Just split up the definition and apply the timeout conditionally:

```java
Observable<String> obs = Observable.fromCallable(longTask);
if (condition) {
   obs = obs.timeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
return obs.onErrorResumeNext(err -> ...);
```